# How to add custom validator to a FormArray?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-forms, angular-validation

I want to add custom validator to form in order to prevent mat-step switching to next step. All works well when I use FormGroups but I fail to achieve validation when I have to use FormArray.

I've tried at least two variants of assigning validator on form initialization:

- inside array

`statuses: this._formBuilder.array([this.createStatus()], defaultStatusValidator())`

- inside parent form of array

`this.productionLineStatuses = this._formBuilder.group({statuses: this._formBuilder.array([this.createStatus()])}, 
{validator: defaultStatusValidator()});`

But this attempts are causing error (probably when casting validator):

```
TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object 
    at Function.keys (<anonymous>)
    at FormGroup.validate [as validator] (default-status.directive.ts:6)
    at FormGroup._runValidator (forms.js:3438)
    at FormGroup.updateValueAndValidity (forms.js:3399)
    at new FormGroup (forms.js:4097)
    at FormBuilder.group (forms.js:7578)
    at CreateProductionLineComponent.ngOnInit (create-production-line.component.ts:31)
```

In the following case error is not thrown, but validator is not working too.
Here is rest of my code and my custom validator:

```js
ngOnInit() {
    this.productionLineDetails = this._formBuilder.group({
      productType: ['', Validators.required],
      language: ['', Validators.required],
      name: ['', Validators.required],
      description: [''],
    });
    this.productionLineStatuses = this._formBuilder.group({
      statuses: this._formBuilder.array([
        this.createStatus()
      ])
    }, defaultStatusValidator());
    this.statuses = this.productionLineStatuses.get('statuses') as FormArray;
    this.statusError = false;
  }
```

validator:

```js
export function defaultStatusValidator(): ValidatorFn {
    return function validate (statuses: FormArray) {
    let defaultCounter = 0;
    Object.keys(statuses.value.controls).forEach(key => {
        const control = statuses.value.controls[key];

        if (control.value.default == true) {
            defaultCounter ++;
        }
      });
    return (defaultCounter > 1) ? {moreThanOneStatusIsDefault: true} : null;
    };
}
```

How should I properly add validator to FormArray?

Comment: You are trying to add defaultStatusValidator as a validator but end up calling it instead defaultStatusValidator(). That is why you get the error. Remove the parenthesis that executes the function call

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have considered if your FormArray is a FormArray of FormControls or a FormArray of FormGroups, but the problem is how you iterate over the controls,

A simple example of both

```js
export function customValidateArray(): ValidatorFn {
    return (formArray:FormArray):{[key: string]: any} | null=>{
      let valid:boolean=true;
      formArray.controls.forEach((x:FormControl)=>{
          valid=valid && x.value=="a"
      })
      return valid?null:{error:'Not all a'}
    }
  };

export function customValidateArrayGroup(): ValidatorFn {
    return (formArray:FormArray):{[key: string]: any} | null=>{
      let valid:boolean=true;
      formArray.controls.forEach((x:FormGroup)=>{
          valid=valid && x.value.name=="a" 
      })
      return valid?null:{error:'Not all name are a'}
    }
  };
```

You can see an example in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ktzv69?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

NOTE: To create the form, I use the constructor of FormGroup, FormControl and FormArray, but you can use FormBuilder too.

NOTE 2: it's not necesary enclose a FormArray in a FormGroup

Comment: About note 2: what do you mean? mat-step uses FormGrops per each step. How to use it other way? Even if it is possible, I'll still stick to parent FormGruop to make all code in a module consistent.

Comment: It's only that several times I see create a formGroup with an only one field, that is a FormArray, and it's innecesary) in the stackblitz you can see how manage the formArray, -iterating over formArray.controls and using the variable of the for as formGroup or a formControl-. Anyway, a FormArray is a FormGroup too, so e.g. in a mat-steper you can use a `stepControl` the formArray and as `formGroup` formArray.at(0) and formArray.at(1). see https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ejtr91?file=app/stepper-label-position-bottom-example.html.We can think a FormArray as "array" of formControls/formGroup

Comment: The answer is indeed correct. However, strict typing will generate an error in recent angular versions ( v15 at least ). The argument type is an AbstractControl. You can easily assert it inside the validator function code. The primary reason is that ValidatorFn can be provided in any control, may it be FormArray, FormGroup or a FormControl and you want to be sure that the given function is only applicable to FormArrays

Comment: @LookForAngular, The solution is write some like: `return (control:AbstractControl){ const formArray=control as FormArray;...rest of the code`

Comment: @Eliseo Yes, and you may want to be sure to check if the control is indeed a form array. What happen at runtime if you provide this function to a FormControl? it will error for sure. Last time I did something like this, i returned a null and a waning ( via console.warn ). This is something that can only be narrowed at runtime. Moreover 
FormArray is a class, you can ensure runtime type safety using `if ( control instanceOf FormArray )`