# How to set validators for a form control inside a formArray in angular

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms, angular-formbuilder

I'm trying to set a validator inside a formArray in angular and I don't know how to create it, my formGroup is

```
 itemsForm = this.fb.group({
    array: this.fb.array([this.fb.control(['']).setValidators(Validators.required)]),
  });
```

I tryed setting the validator inside the array but in the html it let me add another field without validated if this is empty or not my code is this:

**HTML**

```
<section [formGroup]="itemsForm" class="m-5">
  <section
    formArrayName="array"
    class="justify-content-center d-flex flex-wrap"
  >
    <div>
      <section class="d-flex flex-wrap">
        <div class="">
          <h4>Items Selected</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="">
          <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="addItem()">Add Item</button>
        </div>
      </section>

      <section class="d-flex flex-column">
        <div
          class="form-group d-flex flex-row align-items-center"
          *ngFor="let item of itemsArray.controls; let index = index"
        >
          <h2 class="mr-2">item</h2>
          <input
            type="text"
            [formControlName]="index"
            class="form-control"
            [ngClass]="{
              'is-invalid': item.touched  && !item.valid
            }"
          />
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  </section>
</section>
```

**TS**

```
  @Input() defaultOption: string = '';
  @Input() optionsList: Array<string> = [];
  @Output() optionSelected = new EventEmitter<string>();

  selected: string = '';
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}
  itemsForm = this.fb.group({
    array: this.fb.array([this.fb.control(['']).setValidators(Validators.required)]),
  });


  get itemsArray(){
    return this.itemsForm.get('array') as FormArray
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  updateSelection() {
    this.optionSelected.emit(this.selected);
  }
  addItem() {
    this.itemsArray.push(this.fb.control(''));
  }
```

Comment: When adding a new formControl is also need add a validator `this.itemsArray.push(this.fb.control('', [Validators.required]))` . Another way is to add a validator for all FormArray for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57794118/how-to-add-custom-validator-to-a-formarray

Comment: Thanks for this example but it is got me errors of invalid type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this...

```
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}
  itemsForm = this.fb.group({
    array: this.fb.array([this._createFormArrayControls()]),
  });


  get itemsArray(){
    return this.itemsForm.get('array') as FormArray
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  private _createFormArrayControls(): FormControl{
   return this.fb.control('', Validators.required)
  }
```

in the future, if you would need to initialize the form array to some default value based on an array you could then convert FormControl to FormGroup and do this:

```
@Input() set items(value: Item[]) {
    itemsForm = this.fb.group({
    array: this.fb.array(value.map(i => this._createFormArrayGroup(i))),
  });
};
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}   
    
  ngOnInit(): void {}

  private _createFormArrayGroup(item?: Item): FormGroup{   
   return this.fb.group({
    myItem: this.fb.control(item.Value, Validators.required)
   })
  }
```

Comment: I'm doing the map to add default values but my itemForm is not adding it, have you any idea?

Comment: if the map is not workings its because `items` is not populated with values. Constructor gets executed very early, before @Input() gets populated. If you move that form initialization code into ngAfterViewInit() lifecycle hook or inside the @Input setter, the data should be there and everything should work as expected. Let me update my answer.

Comment: that is more logic, I found a way to do it, but if you update your answer it will be better