# Custom validator for dynamically generated checkbox in reactive form is not working

Tags: angular, customvalidator

I have created a project in Angular 13 version for validating the dynamically generated checkboxes. I have followed this blog (https://coryrylan.com/blog/creating-a-dynamic-checkbox-list-in-angular). In this blog, there is a custom validation. But the validation is not working for me. The custom validator code is:

```
function minSelectedCheckboxes(min = 1) {
    const myValidator: ValidatorFn = (formArray: FormArray) => {
        const totalSelected = formArray.controls
            .map(control => control.value)
            .reduce((prev, next) => next ? prev + next : prev, 0);
        return totalSelected >= min ? null : { required: true };
    };

    return myValidator;
}
```

But I am getting the below error. Can anyone help me to solve the error?

> src/app/app.component.ts:62:8 - error TS2322: Type '(formArray:
> FormArray) => { required: boolean; } | null' is not assignable to type
> 'ValidatorFn'.   Types of parameters 'formArray' and 'control' are
> incompatible.
> Type 'AbstractControl' is missing the following properties from type 'FormArray': controls, at, push, insert, and 6 more.
>
> 62  const myValidator: ValidatorFn = (formArray: FormArray) => {
> ~~~~~~~~~~~

[image]

Comment: Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57794118/how-to-add-custom-validator-to-a-formarray

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ValidatorFn` has the following type:

```js
export declare interface ValidatorFn {
    (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null;
}
```

So you need to change the function like this:

```js
function minSelectedCheckboxes(min = 1) {
  const myValidator: ValidatorFn = (control: AbstractControl) => {
    const formArray = control as FormArray;
    const totalSelected = formArray.controls
      .map((control) => control.value)
      .reduce((prev, next) => (next ? prev + next : prev), 0);
    return totalSelected >= min ? null : { required: true };
  };

  return myValidator;
}
```